# C++ / CMake : Making a plugin system for many 'source plugins'

Tags: c++, plugins, cmake

I am working on a C++ library consisting of many plugins, which can be included independently of each other. The set of plugins is only dependent on the users requirements at compile time.
The plugins are source code only, they are not standalone binaries.
For this purpose, the main (and only) `CMakeLists.txt` of the library has a predefined plugins list, and every plugin found in a `plugins` directory is added to the binary target. 
In addition, a preprocessor `#define` with the name of the plugin is set:

```
set (plugins
    plugin1
    plugin2
    plugin3
     ...)

#optional plugins 
foreach(library ${plugins})
    file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "plugins/${library}" librarypath)
    get_filename_component(librarypath ${librarypath} ABSOLUTE) 
    if(EXISTS ${librarypath})
        message("--> found ${library}")
        include_directories(${librarypath}/include)
        file(GLOB libsources "${librarypath}/src/*.cpp" "${librarypath}/src/*.f90")
        set(sources ${sources} ${libsources})
        string(TOUPPER ${library} LIBRARY)
        add_definitions(-D${LIBRARY})
    endif()
endforeach(library)
```

Now in my main library, what I basically do is the following:

```
#ifdef PLUGIN1
#    include "plugin1.h"
#endif
#ifdef PLUGIN2
#    include "plugin2.h"
#endif
#ifdef PLUGIN3
#    include "plugin3.h"
#endif

...

// each plugin has a unique id:
enum PluginID : int {
    Plugin1                          = 1,
    Plugin2                          = 2,
    Plugin3                          = 3,
};

// the name of each plugin is associated with its ID, 

PluginID getPluginIDFromName( const std::string& PluginName )
{
    static std::map<std::string, PluginID> PluginIDMap = {
        {"PLUGIN1", Plugin1},
        {"PLUGIN2", Plugin2},
        {"PLUGIN3", Plugin3},
    };

    return PluginIDMap[PluginName];
}

// Load a plugin by its ID
PluginBaseClass* pluginFactory( PluginID  pluginID)
{
    switch ( pluginID ) {
        #ifdef PLUGIN1 
        case Plugin1: { return new class Plugin1();}
        #endif
       #ifdef PLUGIN2 
        case Plugin2: { return new class Plugin2();}
        #endif
       #ifdef PLUGIN3 
        case Plugin3: { return new class Plugin3();}
       #endif
}}
```

So the result is that in the main source I can load the plugin via:

```
PluginBaseClass* thePlugin1 = pluginFactory ( getPluginIDFromName ("PLUGIN1") );
```

Everything works as intended, but I feel that what I do is some kind of abusing cmake and preprocessor macros. Is there any better way to achieve my goals? 
In addition, manually updating the `map` and `switch` for each possible plugin is rather cumbersome.
The requirement I have is that the user should not need to modify `CMakeLists.txt` manually. Thank you in advance!

Edit: I want to make the plugins available both via their IDs or their names, hence the two functions. In addition, static linking is preferred; I see no reason for dynamic loading.

Comment: Implement the plugin system as dynamic modules. This way u can build 'em separately (e.g., even as a completely separate project).

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer static linking; There is no real need for dynamic loading.

Comment: Why no dynamic loading? For example, on Linux,  `dlopen` is the canonical way to load a plugin (otherwise, don't call it a plugin, but a software component)

Comment: The truth is, that not all 'plugins' are completely independent of each other. Some plugins import or reuse functions and classes of other plugins.This means that at least under Windows symbols must be exported/imported and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually creating the mapping from id to plugin name and the factory function by hand you can use what is known as "self-registration" and have the compiler do most of the work for you.

### A static plugin factory

First, we need a factory class where the individual plugins can register themselves. The declaration might look something like this:

```
class PluginFactory
{
public:
  using PluginCreationFunctionT = PluginBaseClass(*)();

  PluginFactory() = delete;

  static bool Register(std::string_view plugin name,
                       PluginID id,
                       PluginCreationFunctionT creation_function);

  static PluginBaseClass* Create(std::string_view name);
  static PluginBaseClass* Create(PluginID id);

private:
  static std::map<std::string_view, PluginCreationFunctionT> s_CreationFunctionByName;
  static std::map<PluginID, PluginCreationFunctionT> s_CreationFunctionById;
};
```

The corresponding source file then contains

```
std::map<std::string_view, PluginFactory::PluginCreationFunctionT>
PluginFactory::s_CreationFunctionByName;

std::map<PluginID, PluginFactory::PluginCreationFunctionT>
PluginFactory::s_CreationFunctionById;

bool PluginFactory::Register(std::string_view const plugin name,
                             PluginId const id,
                             PluginCreationFunctionT const creation_function)
{
  // assert that no two plugins accidentally try to register
  // with the same name or id
  assert(s_CreationFunctionByName.find(name) == s_CreationFunctionByName.end());
  assert(s_CreationFunctionById.find(id) == s_CreationFunctionById.end());

  s_CreateFunctionByName.insert(name, creation_function);
  s_CreateFunctionById.insert(id, creation_function);

  return true;
}

PluginBaseClass* PluginFactory::Create(std::string_view const name)
{
  auto const it = s_CreationFunctionByName.find(name);
  return it != s_CreationFunctionByName.end() ? it->second() : nullptr;
}

PluginBaseClass* PluginFactory::Create(std::string_view const id)
{
  auto const it = s_CreationFunctionById.find(name);
  return it != s_CreationFunctionById.end() ? it->second() : nullptr;
}
```

Note that `Register` always returns `true` - we'll need it to return a value in order to use the `Register` function as an initializer for a global variable. Being an initializer of a global variable causes the compiler to emit code to call the `Register` function during program startup.

In your main function you can now obtain an instance of a particular plugin via

```
PluginBaseClass* thePlugin1 = PluginFactory::Create("PLUGIN1");
```

or via

```
PluginBaseClass* thePlugin1 = PluginFactory::Create(PluginID::Plugin1);
```

### Modifying the plugins

The plugins themselves now need to be modified so that they register themselves. In theory any global variable would to, but to avoid name clashes between different plugins it is easiest to just add a static data member to each plugin class, e.g.

```
class Plugin1 : public PluginBaseClass {
public:
  ...

private:
  static bool s_IsRegistered;
};
```

and then add the following to the source file for the plugin:

```
namespace {
  PluginBaseClass* create_plugin1()
  {
    return new Plugin1{};
  }
}

bool Plugin1::s_IsRegistered 
  = PluginFactory::Register("PLUGIN1", PluginID::Plugin1, create_plugin1);
```

### Simplifying the CMake code

Now that the compiler generates the mapping you no longer need the preprocessor definitions. All that your CMake-code now needs to do is add the correct include directories and sources. But that doesn't need to be part of the main CMake file. Instead, you can put a CMakeLists.txt into each of the plugin folders and then include them either via `add_subdirectory` or `include` into the main CMakefile:

```
foreach(library ${plugins})
    if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/plugins/${library}/CMakeLists.txt)
      message(STATUS "--> found ${library}"
      include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/plugins/${library}/CMakeLists.txt)
    else()
      message(FATAL "Unknown plugin ${library} requested!")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for plugin1 in the `plugins/plugin1` folder then contains just

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
file(GLOB sources_plugin1 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.f90")
list(APPEND sources ${sources_plugin1})
```

It might not look like much of an improvement in this particular case, but having these separate `CMakeLists.txt` files now also allows conditionally adding dependencies.

For example, assume that Plugin2 is the only plugin that uses boost. With the separate `CMakeLists.txt` you can add everything you need to find and use boost to the `CMakeLists.txt` of Plugin2 without polluting the main `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

1. read plugin list from external file. read [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html). Basically move

> set (plugins
>       plugin1
>       plugin2
>       plugin3
>        ...)

into plugins.cmake file, and use

`include(plugins.cmake)` in your main cmake file.

2. In order to avoid the need to manually modify the map and switch: if it is OK to assume e.g. max number of plugins is 64, you may use bit masks in the following manner:

   ```
           auto plugin_mask = PLUGINS;
   auto id = 1;

   while (plugin_mask)
   {
       if (plugin_mask & 1)
       {
           // found plugin

           // add to map
           std::pair<std::string, PluginID> p;
           p.first = "PLUGIN" + std::to_string(id);
           p.second = static_cast<PluginID>(id++);
           PluginIDMap.insert(p);
       } plugin_mask >> 1;
   }
   ```

Comment: Yup, also you don't really need to assume any max number of plugins, you can use `std::bitset`